# How to set property of different custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, properties

First of all, this is how I dequeue my `cells`:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
        {
            UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"TableViewCellLabel" bundle:nil];
            [tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellLabel"];

            cell = (TableViewCellLabel *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellLabel"];
        }
            break;

        case 1:
        {
            UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"TableViewCellTextfield" bundle:nil];
            [tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellTextfield"];

            cell = (TableViewCellTextfield *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellTextfield"];
        }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
```

And then, I would set their property in `willDisplayCell` delegate method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // set transparent cell bg
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    // init cell view
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
        {
            ((TableViewCellLabel *)cell).tableViewCellType = TableViewCellTypeLabel;
            ((TableViewCellLabel *)cell).delegate = self;
        }
            break;

        case 1:
        {
            ((TableViewCellTextfield *)cell).tableViewCellType = TableViewCellTypeTextfield;
            ((TableViewCellTextfield *)cell).delegate = self;
        }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

My expected result was two different `tableViewCellType` property value, but it ended up two `cells` holding the same type `TableViewCellTypeLabel`. I can't figure out where have I done wrong so I need some help. Thank you.

Comment: Unrelated but never register cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first register nibs in tableView at `viewDidLoad()` of controller.
Then, if you separate your table view for two sections, in first you want to display cells of `CellLabel` type, and in second section cells of `CellTextfield` type, you should switch case not row of IndexPath in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, but `indexPath.section` (you must return 2 sections count in dataSource method) and not to register anything in there. If you need just 2 rows - don't change your `switch indexPath.row code`.
Next you should setup your cell (set `delegate` and `tableViewCellType`) in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method right after dequeue. This will allow you not to lead type implicitly second time.
And at the end of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method you return you cell instance configured.
Example in swift (in obj-c same, structure is important here):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var nib = UINib.init(nibName: "TableViewCellLabel", bundle: nil)
    self.tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellLabel")
    nib = UINib.init(nibName: "TableViewCellTextfield", bundle: nil)
    self.tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellTextfield")
}
```

CellForRow:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        guard let cellLabel = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellLabel") as? TableViewCellLabel else {
            return cell
        }

        cellLabel.tableViewCellType = TableViewCellTypeLabel
        cellLabel.delegate = self

        return cellLabel
    case 1:
        guard let cellField = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellTextfield") as? TableViewCellTextfield else {
            return cell
        }
        cellField.tableViewCellType = TableViewCellTypeTextfield
        cellField.delegate = self

        return cellField
    default:
        return cell
    }
}
```

And clear for me, please: you return 1 section in `numberOfSections` and 2 in `numberOfRowsInSection`? If you have static number on cells in project use static cells: initialize them separately, keep lazy properties, return when you exactly want it to be returned. And this case you will not use `dequeueReusableCell`.

Comment: "you return 1 section in numberOfSections and 2 in numberOfRowsInSection?" Yes I did.

Comment: @Jeff, ok, change indexPath.section to indexPath.row in switch in my code. And if you don't expect other cell objects to appear in table view - make table view static and don't use dequeue.

Comment: how do I keep and return static cells?

Comment: I have made static cells and they are showing. However the type issue is still persists.

Comment: I solved the issue. I was referring to `tableViewCellType` at the creation of `cell`, so the type shown was default value instead of assigned value. I was doing some operations based on `tableViewCellType` at `cell` creation. I solved it by creating a `function` and calling the `function` manually at `property` setting.